# few questions about building apps for phones?

Tags: windows

I have a few questions for building apps.

1. Can u make apps using c++?
2. How do I get an app from my testing environment onto my windows phone 8?
3. Do I have to worry about cross phone compatibility?

paying $200 to put apps on the marketplace is extremely out of the question. I just want to test my app on my actual phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to develop windows phone 8 apps, and yes you can develop using c++, but you have to read up on async await, as the sdk have tons of it in order to give the fluid user experience.

And the last time I checked, the developer account only costs $25 now

Comment: Check out this link, http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2013/11/06/microsoft-merges-windows-store-windows-phone-developer-accounts-lowers-annual-price-19/ I guess it will excite you more

Answer (score 0):

1. Well Yes!
2. You need to unlock your Windows Phone to actually test in on a Hardware Device.
3. You don't need to worry about the compatibility, but you should take note of the High-Res Phones that are in the Market too.